# JSON.parse incorrect string format

Tags: javascript, parsing, replace, format, stringify

i have this string:

```
"{\\'Ovcount\\':\\'0\\',\\'S1\\':\\'LU\\',\\'S2\\':\\'NewClientOrMove\\',\\'memoToDisplay\\':\\'LU -- New Client or Move\\\"}";
```

and i want it to become like this:

```
'{"Ovcount":"0","S1":"LU","S2":"NewClientOrMove","memoToDisplay":"LU -- New Client or Move"}'
```

I tried with stringify and replace and i ended up with

```
"{'Ovcount':'0','S1':'LU','S2':'NewClientOrMove','memoToDisplay':'LU -- New Client or Move"}"
```

And from here i wanted to replace the single quotation marks `'` with double quotation marks `"` but when i did, in beginning and ending of the string appeared an extra `"\`

```
"\ "{"Ovcount":"0","S1":"LU","S2":"NewClientOrMove","memoToDisplay":"LU -- New Client or Move\"}\ ""
```

Any tips on how to get the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var result = "{\'Ovcount\':\'0\',\'S1\':\'LU\',\'S2\':\'NewClientOrMove\',\'memoToDisplay\':\'LU -- New Client or Move\"}"
  .replaceAll("'", '"')
  .replaceAll('\\', '');
console.log(result);
```

this got me what you wanted, it replaces all the single quotes with double quotes, then it  removes any back slashes

the result is

> '{"Ovcount":"0","S1":"LU","S2":"NewClientOrMove","memoToDisplay":"LU
> -- New Client or Move"}'